# AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUpload

Tags: visual-studio-2012, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I'am using AjaxFileUpload control in my asp.net form application. One of the file contains ‘&’ symbol with file name like this AFFILIATES & RESELLERS_id_2.gif.I don’t permission to change the file name to remove special characters in that file name. Getting Content type as empty and not saving image in destination path

please suggest me how can I resolve this problem.

Is there any validation property for AjaxFileUpload control like ‘HasFile’ property of Fileupload control?

Why AjaxFileUpload control not accepting special characters in file name.

```
<asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="FileUploadAjax" runat="server" Width="600px" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg,gif,png" Font-Size="12px" OnUploadComplete="FileUploadAjax_UploadComplete" />

  protected void FileUploadAjax_UploadComplete(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
    {

        FileUploadAjax.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["portfolioimggallery"]));
        //fileuploadajaxlist.Add(FileUploadAjax, e);

    }
```

Local Debug Result here:

```
-       e   {AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs}    AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs
+       base    {AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs}    System.EventArgs {AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadEventArgs}
        ContentType ""  string
        FileId          "F9DB0007-D821-BB40-42CA-3EF2BB5F7905"  string
        FileName    "AFFILIATES"    string
        FileSize    4705    int
        PostedUrl   ""  string
        State           Success AjaxControlToolkit.AjaxFileUploadState
        StatusMessage   "Success"   string
+       Non-Public members
```

Comment: So is it breaking after you call SaveAs, or is it breaking before that?

Comment: Which version of ACT and which browser you use? Check request to server on browser console on uploading. Is file name passed via query string?